# What happens to your statistics when you join a Modern Warfare 2 game in the middle?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I guess that you get a win if you win (especially in free-for-all mode).

But if you join a game, any kind of game, and your team loses, does that count as a loss?

If your team wins, does that count as a win?

Comment: I believe that is what happens.

Comment: I don't understand why `first-person-shooter` tag has been added. It's not related to the question. It won't help someone looking about first person shooter game.
I appreciate that someone has corrected by bad english. Thank you!

Comment: Because the game it's about, Modern Warfare 2, is a first person shooter.

Comment: @Powerlord: Does that mean that EVERY question tagged with modern-warfare-2, should also be tagged with first-person-shooter? That's redundant.

Comment: I agree with Carlo, this is an instance where it's specific to Modern Warfare, and not it's FPS attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, if you join a game at the last second (or any time up to then) and the team wins you win, if they lose you lose.

It's happened to me a bunch of times where I'll load in, and go right to the scoreboard with a loss.

Comment: I believe that's incorrect.

Comment: Well, then how about providing that proof?  I've seen it happen to myself and my friends on several instances.

Comment: Can't provide the proof. Please try it yourself. Check your win loss ratio and do absolutely nothing in a game that's already started. It won't affect your W/L.

Comment: This is not entirely accurate, but even after 10's of thousands of games, I can't claim to know the exact mechanic. It seems like it doesn't impact your streak, for one. Also, if you join a game late and don't spawn, but instead let it time out, that seems to save you from the loss.

Answer (score 1):

If you join in the middle of game, and do nothing (no kills, no deaths) you don't get neither a win or a loss. If you kill someone or get killed THEN you'll earn the win or lost.

Answer (score 1):

When you join the game has nothing to do with whether you get a W or an L. If you manage to go an entire game without dying or getting a single kill you do not get a W or an L added to your record. However, this 0-0 K-D  gets you the Accolade AFK (Zero Kills, Zero Deaths).